# pdfkit django in digitalocean

Tags: django, python-3.x, pdfkit

pdfkit works in the local machine everything works successfully displays as pdf, but in digitalocean sends to the server error 500, why?

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import pdfkit
from .models import Buses

    def pdf(request, id):
        bus = Buses.objects.get(id=id)
        template = get_template('buses/pdf.html')
        html = template.render({'bus': bus})
        options = {
            'page-size': 'Letter',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
        }

        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, options)
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}_{}.pdf"'.format(bus.company, bus.name)

        return response
```

Comment: Can you please add error log?

Comment: For PDF generation, usually some binary needs to be installed on VM. Did you install all required dependencies?

Comment: @narendra-choudhary  i install only pip pdfkit

Comment: pdfkit depends on wkhtmltopdf. Did you install wkhtmltopdf? Source: https://github.com/JazzCore/python-pdfkit

Comment: @narendra-choudhary yes, i install wkhtmltopdf, but doesnt work pdfkit? it send to server error 500

Comment: Can you please add error log?

Comment: @narendra-choudhary  doesn show error, simple get in browser server error 500

Comment: @narendra-choudhary wkhtmltopdf qt.qpa.screen: qxcbconnection: could not connect to display

Comment: Try installing a newer version of wkhtmltopdf. Check this [issue](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/2037).

Answer (score 0):

If your template references other files, you may need to set `'enable-local-file-access': True` in your options.

See: https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf/issues/4460

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but your problem could be the location of wkhtmltopdf
It is always a better option to specify the wkhtmltopdf location. So on your digital ocean server - start by installing wkhtmltopdf - if you dont have it yet.

This is a great tutorial to use for any version of Ubuntu - https://computingforgeeks.com/install-wkhtmltopdf-on-ubuntu-debian-linux/

Then on your command line:

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

Note the location, your code will then look like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template.loader import get_template
import pdfkit
from .models import Buses

    def pdf(request, id):
        bus = Buses.objects.get(id=id)
        template = get_template('buses/pdf.html')
        html = template.render({'bus': bus})
        options = {
            'page-size': 'Letter',
            'encoding': "UTF-8",
        }
        config = pdfkit.configuration(wkhtmltopdf='/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf') #use your actual location here


        pdf = pdfkit.from_string(html, False, configuration=config, options=options)
        response = HttpResponse(pdf, content_type='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}_{}.pdf"'.format(bus.company, bus.name)

        return response
```